# How can I get a DOM element generated by script?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get a DOM element by clicking on it. The script looks like this:

```js
document.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    e.target.style.color = "white";
    alert(e.target.tagName);
    for (let attr of e.target.attributes) {
        alert( `${attr.name} = ${attr.value}` );
    };
};
```

The script works fine for the HTML elements, but it does not work for the elements generated by script. Actually nothing happens while I am clicking on the dropdown and selecting a value from it (no alert appears). Google Dev tools displays the element and some of its attributes including its id as far as I can see is autogenerated. I even can use its autogenerated id for doing automation job with this element. But is their any way to catch the element with my script?

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. We can only guess without being able to inspect in dev tools ourselves. One possibility is those elements are in an iframe for example

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am not able to provide the original web page as it is internal company product, but I have found something similar that can be checked and by the way in this case it looks like the reason of not working script is different that those I have with auto generated elements in my original application. As you can see for the general Google page the script does not work for any element located on the page, but for the Google URL shown on the second image the same script works fine for all elements located on the page. And the shovn element itself is differnt (represented by div on the first image and by img on the second)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The reason it does not work for dynamically generated elements is simply because event listener is bound upfront on pre-existing elements.

You should have a function that **re-binds the event** every time a **new element** is added to the DOM. The function should be either targeted for the single element, or whole page.

```
window.onElementAdded = (element) = >{
      element.onclick = ...
}
```

This function needs to be invoked every time an element is added to the DOM from your code.

Comment: The listener is being added to the `document` so it doesn't matter when elements within it are added